# In constructor theory, are contradictory properties possible?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm trying to understand [constructor theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_theory). In particular, I'm trying to understand impossibility.

Suppose that I have two tasks which build comparable but incompatible states.

For example, both tasks prepare an electron, but one task prepares an electron which will measure spin-up and the other task prepares an electron which will measure spin-down. While a constructor might be able to carry out either task, it can't somehow combine the tasks and produce an electron which is simultaneously spin-up and spin-down. Certainly, it can put the tasks into superposition, which would be a third task distinct from the first two tasks since it is not guaranteed to measure either spin-up or spin-down.

This isn't a fault of the constructor; no constructor could do this, because the properties of the constructed states are inherently contradictory.

Nonetheless, **are contradictory properties possible?** I would like my intuition checked.

Comment: Upon request, I can restate that second paragraph using electrons or photons, since constructor theory really wants to talk about QM states. However, this isn't a question about QM, but about constructions.

Comment: Presumably a minimal example would be a constructor that can make a spin up or a spin down electron?

Comment: I'm not the expert on constructor theory, but IMHO there's no physical law which would forbid a ball to look blue and red at the same time. Such intermediate color would be purple. However your custom constructor must know how to interpolate between these two colors. Yet, you can build a constructor which shows ball completely in red and after fraction of second turns it into a blue and then back again to red. So really this boils down on _exact_ specification on constructor which you are trying to build.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas: Fine, this is now a question about electrons. I'm a little grumpy that you can't let us have nice things; this isn't a question about colored spheres.

Comment: I understand, so maybe analogy with colored spheres is simply inappropriate here ?

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas: It was a fine analogy -- there is no purple wavelength of photons! It's a little frustrating that I have to be so detailed when the literature of constructor theory is so painfully vague.

Comment: I am pretty sure a constructor performing the task of putting an electron in the state spin up *and* spin down would be called *impossible* in the language of constructor theory. (It can not only not be done with arbitrary precision, it can't be done at all).